# How to alter auto-complete exposed filter programmatically?

Tags: 7, views

[image]I created a views to show parent and child term together using autocomplete expose filter .. but its show only one child. I have same child for two different parent.but its show only one child.
how to change this programmatically using view query alter. I need such type:

```
Parent . Parent-1
           locality-1
           locality-2
         parent-2
           locality-2
           locality-4
```

I need such type of result on autocomplete expose filter.

Comment: Do you only want to do it with hook_views_query_alter?
hook_form_alter would also be an option, I could provide a code example for that.

Comment: It would be great help.

Comment: I have try lot of module .. but still not find a way to achive this using module. So finally I want to fix this via custom code.

Comment: Please provide me code example.

Comment: Hey there, I will do, need a little time though. :-)

Comment: Hello there, I am reading your question again. Just to be sure, you need a taxonomy exposed filter in a view that shows content? Or something else?

Comment: yes I need taxonomy autocomplete expose filter . with parent and child term.

Comment: Okey, one last question. If the child term has many parents, then selecting any of the instances of that child term will have the same filtering effect. Is that what is expected?

Comment: we have same child with different parent ..

Comment: did you have a look at the answer? would it work for you?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a possible answer to this problem.
First of all, a litte visual.

[image]

To get this working you need the following:

- Configure your View to display the exposed taxonomy filter as a dropdown. autcomplete will not work because you cannot have multiple entries with the same key in the generated JSON array.
- Optional: Install and configure the Chosen module [https://www.drupal.org/project/chosen] to get your dropdown to render nicely and offer autocomplete options.

  - You will also need this JS library for Chosen to work => [https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen]
- Optional: You can finally use some custom code for formatting the presentation of your list, here is a sample minimal module that adds the special arrow that you see in the screenshot.

```
define('YOUR_CUSTOM_TAXONOMY_AUTOCOMPLETE_PATH', 'mycustompath/1');
define('YOUR_EXPOSED_FILTER_MACHINE_NAME', 'field_tags_tid');

/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter()
 */
function se_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if( $form_id == 'views_exposed_form' ){
    if(isset($form[YOUR_EXPOSED_FILTER_MACHINE_NAME]) && 
    $form[YOUR_EXPOSED_FILTER_MACHINE_NAME]['#type'] == 'select'){
      $form[YOUR_EXPOSED_FILTER_MACHINE_NAME]['#options'] = _custom_update_options_for_taxonomy($form[YOUR_EXPOSED_FILTER_MACHINE_NAME]['#options']);
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Function that update select options for taxonomy filter
 * 
 */
function _custom_update_options_for_taxonomy($options = array()) {
  $current_parent = '';
  foreach( $options as $i=>$option ) {
    if( is_int($i) && isset($option->option) && is_array($option->option) ) {
      $option_arr = $option->option;
      $tids = array_keys($option_arr);
      $tid = reset($tids);
      // is this a child of the previous parent
      if( strpos($option_arr[$tid], '-') === 0 && $current_parent != '') {
        $option_arr[$tid] = preg_replace('/^-/', ' ⤷ ', $option_arr[$tid]);
        $option->option = $option_arr;
      }
      // this is a parent node
      else {
        $current_parent = $option_arr[$tid];
      }
    }
  }
  return $options;
}
```

Hope this help some!